# Unable to register warranty for PS5

Tags: ps5

Bought my PS5 couple of days ago and tried to register my warranty online. It requires me to select the model number as well as the 17 digits serial number which I did. I tried to register it but it keeps saying invalid serial number. I've double checked to make sure my S/N is correctly entered.

I had a PS4 pro few years ago and remember I was able to do so with the same steps as above. I'm not sure what is going on. I called the Playstation support hotline (based in Hong Kong) and they seemed blur about the issue.

Has anyone experienced this before and how do you resolved it?

Is the warranty automatically registered or do you have to do it manually like I did?